# Solutions of an equation

Tags: functions

Problem:

> Find all real solutions for $x$ in
>   $$ 2(2^x- 1) x^2 + (2^{x^2}-2)x = 2^{x+1} -2 . $$

I know that you can move all the terms to one side, then divide by $2$ and factor, but what next?

Comment: $$(2^x-1)(x^2-1)+x(2^{x^2-1}-1)=0\implies x^2-1=0$$ is a solution

Comment: If I may ask, how did you get from the original equation to $x^2-1=0?$

Comment: $x=0$ is one solution.

Comment: there are three real solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We seek all real solutions for $2(2^x-1)x^2+\left(2^{x^2}-2\right)x=2^{x+1}-2$.

Let's rewrite our equation into a *very* interesting form.

\begin{align}
2(2^x-1)x^2+\left(2^{x^2}-2\right)x&=2^{x+1}-2\\
2(2^x-1)x^2+\left(2^{x^2}-2\right)x-2^{x+1}+2&=0&&\text{Set equation = 0}\\
(2^x-1)x^2+\left(2^{x^2-1}-1\right)x-2^x+1&=0&&\text{Divide all terms by 2}\\
(2^x-1)x^2+\left(2^{x^2-1}-1\right)x-(2^x-1)&=0&&\text{Factor out $-1$}\\
(2^x-1)(x^2-1)+\left(2^{x^2-1}-1\right)x&=0&&\text{Factor out $2^x-1$}\\
(2^x-1)y+x(2^y-1)&=0\tag{1}\label{eq}&&\text{Replace $x^2-1$ with $y$}
\end{align}

Notice the symmetry of the left-hand side of Equation \ref{eq}. Also notice that if $x=0$, then $2^x-1=0$ as well.

The solutions of Equation \ref{eq} must be values such that $x=0$ or $y=x^2-1=0$. Therefore the solutions are $x=0, 1, -1$.